# Python pandas read_csv for specfic records in columns

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import data from a large csv file 15GB+. I have to select few columns with specific values (there are over 50 columns) but as an example. I have used

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', nrows=10000, usecols=['ID', State'])
```

Is there a way where I can specify something like that:

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', nrows=10000, usecols=['ID', 'State'='abc'])
```

Can't find any option to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to filter rows like that while reading csv files. 
What you can do is create an iterator then apply your filter to each chunk then concat the chunks. It would look something like:

```
iterable = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols=['ID', 'State'], iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['State'] == 'abc'] for chunk in iterable])
```

Comment: Worked for me. The execution time was 8min!
How to find out the optimum chunk size ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the resulting DataFrame for a selection where 'State' == 'abc' is small enough to be accommodated in RAM, you could extract those from the csv as follows. df is the resultant DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd 

inPath = 'filename.csv'
chunkSize = 10000 #size of chunks relies on your available memory

tmpDf = pd.read_csv(inPath,chunksize=chunkSize, 
            usecols=['ID', 'State'])
for chunk in tmpDf:
    try:
        df
    except NameError:
        df = tmpDf[tmpDf['State'] == 'abc']
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, tmpDf[tmpDf['State'] == 'abc']])
```